# Group By Using Wildcards in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this query:

```
SELECT SomeTableA.*
FROM SomeTableB
LEFT JOIN SomeTableA USING (XYZ)
GROUP BY SomeTableA.*
```

I know that I cannot do the GROUP BY part with wildcards. At the same time, I don't really like listing all the columns (can be up to 20) manually.

Could this be added as new feature? Or is there any way how to easily get the list of all 20 columns from SomeTableA for the GROUP BY part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have the exact query shown in your question - then try below instead - no grouping required

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `project.dataset.tableA`
WHERE xyz IN (SELECT xyz FROM `project.dataset.tableB`)
```

As of `Group By Using Wildcards in Big Query` this sounds more like `grouping by struct` which is not supported so you can submit feature request if you want - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0